# How to check only numbers in value - Lua

Tags: lua

I want to make sure players can't put letters or symbols in the value, how do I check if it is a number only?

```lua
function seed1()
    ESX.UI.Menu.CloseAll()

    ESX.UI.Menu.Open('dialog', GetCurrentResourceName(), 'amountseed1', {
        title = 'Shop'
    }, function(data, menu)
        local amount = tostring(data.value)
        if amount == nil then
            ...
        else
            [[What should i put here to check its only contain number ?]]
        end
    end, function(data, menu)
        menu.close()
    end)
end
```

I can put something like this, but maybe this isn't a good way to do that:

```lua
else 
    if amount > 0 and amount < 9999 then 
         ...
    else 
        print('Invalid amount or amount higher than 9999')
    end
end
```

Comment: It's [Lua](http://lua.org/about.html#name), by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only care about the number, there is no need to convert the value to string:

```lua
local amount = tostring(data.value)
--             ^^^^^^^^ partially useless
```

Instead, go for the number right away:

```lua
local amount = tonumber(data.value)
if amount == nil then
    -- Not a number
else
    -- A number
end
```

In the end, remember that [`tonumber`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-tonumber) attempts to convert the value to a number and returns `nil` in case of a failure.

Comment: Accepted within less than a minute after answering, that's fast :D

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `tostring` with `tonumber`. This will turn strings into numbers if possible, and return `nil` if it can't.

Keep in mind: `tonumber` won't just take the largest valid prefix of a string, so `tonumber("20 foo")` will return `nil` and not `20`. It also supports all ways to write number literals in Lua, so `tonumber("2.3e2")` will return `230` and `tonumber("0xff")` will return `255`.